# Migrating from ArcGIS to gdal

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, gdal, grass-gis

I would like to collect a table of equivalent or close enough gdal based functions to replace ArcGIS functions (esp in spatial analyst). Are there functions available using gdal to perform the following ArcGIS functions:

1. Lookup
2. Zonal statistics
3. Focal statistics
4. Nibble
5. Iterate through raster VAT
6. Combine
7. Mosaic

The key is to have a ready reckoner of such functions, so ArcGIS based code can be relatively painlessly changed to one based on gdal.

Comment: Also, feel free to add recipes that you might think are relevant.

Comment: Are you open to using GRASS (no pun intended)?

Comment: Absolutley, I should have mentioned that!

Comment: I notice that you have not yet taken the [Tour] which is explicit that there should be just one question per question.  Here you are effectively asking seven questions in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Micha's list, here is how you can **nibble** with GRASS

1) mask your image with r.mapcalc

2) with the resulting image, interpolate to the nearest neighbour using [r.surf.nnbathy](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.surf.nnbathy.html)

For **combine**, I would use [r.cross](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.cross.html) but you can also do it using r.mapcalc with this [algorithm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141999/implement-r-cross-arcgis-combine-with-gdal/143897#143897)

For **mosaic**, I would use gdalbuildvrt: it is often not necessary to create a new file, and you can translate it after if it becomes necessary.

As mentioned by @webrian, r.reclass can be used for **lookup**.

VAT's are tables, so you can use table editing tools to update them (see e.g. [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67255/what-are-qgis-arcpy-equivalent-functions-for-update-delete-row-field))

Comment: thanks @radoxju, is there a way to replace the setcursor and updatecursor command in ArcGIS?

Comment: insertCursor and updateCursor are the methods to parse the rows of a table in ArcGIS, so I would say YES(you can update a table in QGIS), but it depends on what you want to do. Many things can be done with the field calculator in QGIS, but if you work with raster this question could help : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107996/how-to-do-loops-on-raster-cells-with-python-console-in-qgis

Comment: By the way, please ask separate questions when you can : you will attract more specific answers.

Comment: sorry about that, will take care...

Answer (score 6):

Here are some options

1. Lookup: (not sure)
2. Zonal stats: The GRASS module r.statistics
3. Focal stats: GRASS r.neighbors
4. Nibble: (don't know)
5. Iterate through VAT: I think that the concept of a VAT is specific to Arc*, but
   r.describe might get close.
6. Combine: Just use GRASS r.mapcalc
7. Mosaic: GRASS - r.patch or gdal_merge

Comment: As far as I understand the Lookup, the GRASS module r.reclass should do it.

Comment: thanks @Micha, will r.describe be able to modify the VAT?

Comment: For zonal statistics, you can also use r.univar, v.rast.stats, v.vect.stats (see at page bottom of http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/keywords.html#zonal%20statistics)

Comment: Please consider to merge your answers also into http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tips_for_Arc_users