# Can you access all tools in python/arcpy regardless of license level?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, basic-license-level, standard-license-level

Is it possible to write a python script using arcpy that is for a tool not included in the current desktop license level?

For example, write something using the [Identity Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000n000000) when you only have a standard license?

Comment: Do you just want to write it, or be able to test it?

Comment: well I can write it, but I want to know if it will work. I have an advanced license with several extensions, but many of my coworkers only have basic or standard and need access occasionally to tools outside of their license level, so I'm trying to find a solution, since upgrading them isn't an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't 'use' the tool if your license doesn't include it. But yes, in some cases, you can definitely create similar/equivalent tools using Python and arcpy. I've done a few over the years.

For a lot of cases, cursors and geometry methods will do a lot of the heavy lifting. Take Buffer as an example, a combination of SearchCursor and InsertCursor paired with the geometry buffer method will take you most of the way.

Answer (score 2):

Seconding @DWynne, you can't use a tool if your license does not allow access to it. You might consider moving at least partly to an open source based solution for the tools you do not have access to. Have a look at [Migrating from ArcGIS to gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144588/migrating-from-arcgis-to-gdal) for a list of alternatives to some of ArcGIS tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools that require an Advanced level license that can have very effective workarounds written using a Basic or Standard level license.  For example, the Frequency tool can be replaced by Summary Statistics with a case field.

However, there are also likely to be many that cannot.

In the example, you give it is very easy to replace the Identity tool with Union followed by Select to choose just those features that have the ID from the `in_features`.